# Passage of time in Patala loka

Tags: bhagavata-purana, time, lokas

It is known from Bhagavatha Purana that passage of time is different in different worlds. Examples are Brahma kidnapping cows and friends of Krishna as described [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/13/). Do our puranas also state that time passes at a different rate in the worlds below earth, for example patala loka, rasatala loka?